# SignalR pool of tasks executing long running job

Tags: c#, asp.net, signalr

I have a SignalR Hub within ASP.Net application that can start different tasks

```
public async Task StartHeatingTask()
{
    await TaskPool.Instance.TryRun<Heating>(identifier, Heating_ReportProgress);
}

...

void Heating_ReportProgress(TaskProgressStatus status, OperationProgressEventArgs[] args)
{
    this.Clients.All.reportProgress(status, args);
}
```

My question is how to avoid double execution of the same task(same by identifier). This is my current implementation of `TaskPool`, though I'm not sure if I'm using combination of `locks` and `await` properly:

```
public class TaskPool
{
    private Dictionary<string, LongRunningJob> pool;
    private object syncRoot = new object();


    public static TaskPool Instance = new TaskPool();

    public async Task TryRun<T>(string identifier, LongRunningJob.Progress progressHandler, bool captureContext = false)
            where T : LongRunningJob, new()
    {
        Task worker = null;

        if (!this.pool.ContainsKey(identifier))
        {
            lock (this.syncRoot)
            {
                if (!this.pool.ContainsKey(identifier))
                {
                    LongRunningJob job = new T {Identifier = identifier};
                    job.ProgressEventHandler += progressHandler;
                    this.pool.Add(identifier, job);

                    worker = job.RunAsync().ContinueWith(task => { this.pool.Remove(identifier); });
                }
            }

            if (worker != null)
            {
                await worker.ConfigureAwait(captureContext);
            }
        }
    }

    public bool Terminate(string identifier)
    {
        if (this.pool.ContainsKey(identifier))
        {
            lock (this.syncRoot)
            {
                if (this.pool.ContainsKey(identifier))
                {
                    this.pool[identifier].Terminate();
                    return true;
                }
            }
        }

        return false;
    }
}
```

Also should I `await` the same task that was started by previous user call. I'm new to `C# 5 Task` so it's quite possible that my concept is wrong at its roots and should be completely redesigned.

https://dotnetfiddle.net/SAeTtj

Comment: FYI, SignalR has `IProgress` support built-in, which is much cleaner than a separate callback.

Comment: Hi Stephen, I'm aware of 'System.Progress<T>' though in my case I feel more comfortable with custom implementation.

Answer (score 1):

what about [BlockingCollection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/dd997371%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)?
I think that in your case it provides what you are looking for:
it is a thread-safe collection with

1. An implementation of the Producer-Consumer pattern.
2. Concurrent adding and taking of items from multiple threads.

in your TaskPool class you can replace

```
private Dictionary<string, LongRunningJob> pool;
```

with

`BlockingCollection<T>` element

Check the examples in [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/dd267312(v=vs.110).aspx) page

You can also use [ConcurrentQueue](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267265.aspx) class for a thread-safe first in-first out (FIFO) collection

Comment: hi faby, thanks for your comment, though my question is more about executing the `TryRun` method for the second time considering same list of parameters. Should I await anything or simply return from the method. Am I awaiting the `worker` properly

Comment: Hi @Andrew, Which is the behavior that you can't perform with BlockingCollection<T>?

Comment: `BlockingCollection` will handle thread safe access to `pool` property. where as my problem is wider - if user `U1` executes `TryRun` and user `U2` does the exact same call...should I await the task that is already running(registered in the pool) or should I simply exit the method(what I do now). Is idea of my `Task pool` good itself? I need to be able to start tasks remotely and get appropriate progress indication...it can be anything - complex business logic routine, generation of data export, application heating...

Comment: If `U1` execute TryRun `U2` can't make the exact same call. You can check this situations maybe with an enum return type (operation still in progress). I think that the exit is the correct way to avoid long pending connections. This because even if the operation is in a background thread it isn't ended.

Comment: `await worker.ConfigureAwait(captureContext);` happens for 1st user only. what should the other user expect? it's now just a return. is that correct behavior?

Comment: where is the return in your TryRun method? why don'y you use something like `return Task.Run(() => AsyncMethod()).Result;`